# How to check with Linux the duration on battery since last full charge?

Tags: linux, duration, battery

On laptop running Linux Debian based, how to check ,or get, the whole duration running on battery since the last full charge? Easy to get the time remaining or battery level, but the total duration on battery since last charge is what I wish to know. In comparison, on Android device, we get the value in battery stats "Last full charge" picture attached. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but you could use 'upower -d' to get changes in state of AC, the 'updated' field. But it does not indicate full charge and it's reset on reboot.

Comment: There are a lot of usefull infos provided by upower... but not the Last full charge, nor uptime.